# How to obtain the 1st and the 15th day of the month for each month (between 1 and 12) in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

How do I obtain the 1st and 15th day of each month for a period between two dates?
Example that does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM daily_data 
WHERE (`date` < '$des' AND `date` > '$has') 
  AND (`date` LIKE  '%-%-01' AND `date` LIKE '%-%-15');
```

Comment: If it is possible, please ask your question in english. The users come all around from the world.

Comment: this is an English-speaking site/Este es un website en inglés.

Answer (score 1):

```
 select * from table where day(date_field) in (1,15)
```

so your query I think it would become

```
select * FROM datos_diarios WHERE Fecha between '$des' and '$has' AND day(Fecha) in (1,15)
```

**edit**.
Just for your knowledge it would be possible to use a wildcard char with like.
Something like this:

```
select * from table 
where 
date_field like '____-__-01'
or 
date_field like '____-__-15'
```

but it's better if you use day() function.

Comment: Muchas, muchas gracias nick rulez, como hago para que si no se encuentra registro tome el valor siguiente.
Realmente me gustaria filtrar los resultados en php, ya que mi intencion es asignar una clave para estos dias, pero regresar el valor, para los otros dias

Comment: Muchas, muchas gracias nick rulez, como hago para que si no se encuentra registro tome el valor siguiente.
Realmente me gustaria filtrar los resultados en php, ya que mi intencion es asignar una clave para estos dias, pero regresar el valor, para los otros.

EJEMPLO NO FUNCIONA!!!
<code>
 $strQuery = "select * FROM datos_diarios WHERE Fecha between '$des' and '$has'"
$result = mysql_query($strQuery) or die(mysql_error());
                if ($result) {
if($ors['Fecha'] == 01 || 15){
....
}
</code>

Comment: Hi Hernan. Sorry but I don't understand Spanish :(